# How can I create a test environment for a file system in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot-test, mockmvc

I'm using Java and Spring Boot for my back end. The back end uses a file system. To test the urls themselves, I use MockMvc. The problem is that the back end creates files in a dynamic environment. I want to have a test folder which the back end uses only when testing. Since the tests are virtually separate from the actual controllers, I cannot configure the test methods to say "Hey back end, this is a test, so use the test data folder instead of the real one".

Comment: Couldn't you test the backend classes directly (i.e., not calling them as web services, but as actual classes) and mock whatever methods actually handle the files?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I wanted to test the specific urls, not the just the methods / classes.

Answer (score 0):

Using system variables, I managed to change the current directory specifically for testing.

```
System.setProperty("user.dir", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\TestData");
```

I used @BeforeAll and @AfterAll (to reset).

Comment: I was about to suggest a similar approach, but based on a separate profile in `application.properties`